# Edit active database on the fly

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

So I'm working on a little web application in which you can manage your database.

Now I can use the following function to retrieve all databases

```
DB::select('SHOW DATABASES')
```

But I now want to be able to get the tables for each of those databases and eventually do more with those databases, but I figured if I get this working that wouldn't be a problem.

Normally you'd have the different database in your config, but since I want my application work with "any" database and make sure I don't have to manually add all the databases etc since that's the kind of work I want my web app done for me.

I've tried tricking around it a bit without success for example.

```
DB:select('USE dbName; SHOW TABLES');
DB::select('SELECT dbName(); SHOW TABLES');
```

Obviously this didn't work, but is there any "proper" solution to this? I thought editing the .env variable on the fly might've been an option, but I can't seem to find a "legit" way to do that either.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this.

> I thought editing the .env variable on the fly might've been an
>   option, but I can't seem to find a "legit" way to do that either.

What you need is this

```
DB::purge('mysql');//IMP

Config::set('database.connections.mysql.host', $host);
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $database);
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.username', $username);
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.password', $password);
```

You just need to figure out a way to get the values for `$host`, `$database`, `$username`, and `$password` dynamically.

One way to do that is have a database which stores all these values and point the default database connection (say `mysql` in `config/database.php`) to it. Then read values from it on the fly and set the connections accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's enough to simply re-assign config values? What if the DB manager/connection has already been initialised, with the original config values? You would need to do this somewhere in bootstrap

Comment: Of course, the DB manager is already initialized with the default values from the `.env`. Wherever you use that code, the config values will be specific to that object only. Let's say you are setting the config in `MyController` class, then the config will be specific to that particular `MyController` instance. The rest of the system will continue using the default connection.